# Can I award bounty to two answers?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Recently I asked a question and decided to award a bounty on its answer, Here it is

[Bring an element to top of the page even if the page does not scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196723/bring-an-element-to-top-of-the-page-even-if-the-page-does-not-scroll)

I have selected an answer and I have awarded the bounty as well, but there is another answer which is also very good and he/she has put in some good effort on that answer. I know I can only select 1 answer as correct and I have already done so but I wish to award some bounty to the other answer as well.

Question is, can I? Even if it is other than what I have already awarded

Comment: Yes, you can create a second bounty to award another answer.

Comment: great, can you please let me know how? I cant find the bounty link on that question anymore

Comment: There should be a "start a bounty" link that is below all the comments on the question.

Comment: Strange, I didn't see it until I refreshed just now. Maybe that link gets hidden for some time after a bounty is awarded? Thank you so much

Comment: Note that it will have to be double your previous bounty though. Unless you already awarded a 500rep bounty.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that, that's a bummer! I'll have to excuse that expedition of awarding 200 more bounty :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: @Bart To quote from the bounty FAQ: "If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, you can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as you like"

Comment: Applied a workaround :)

Comment: Wow @alecxe that was so very nice of you